# Constructing a $C^{\infty}$ function whose derivatives at the endpoints of an interval are all given

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am wondering whether, given 2 sequences of real numbers $(u_n)_\mathbb{N}$ and $(v_n)_\mathbb{N}$, it is always possible to find a $C^\infty$ function $f$ on the closed interval $[a;b]$ such that

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f^{(n)}(a)=u_n$ and $f^{(n)}(b)=v_n$

(This is clearly impossible using polynomials or power series in the general case, but the example of $x \mapsto \exp(-|\frac{1}{x}|)$ shows that a $C^\infty$ function is not entirely determined by the values of its derivatives at a point.)

What motivates my question is that if the answer is yes, then this would allow, given 2 $C^\infty$ functions on the intervals $[a;b]$ and $[c;d]$ with $b<c$, to "patch" them together to form a $C^{\infty}$ function on $[a;d]$.

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

Thhis is a special case  of [Whitney's extension theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) where $K=\{a,b\}$
.